# An element belongs to a union of a collection of subsets iff that element belongs to a subset of the collection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be a set and $\{S_i\}_{i\in I}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(S)$ a collection of subsets for some index set $I$. I often see the following statement:
$$x\in\bigcup_{i\in I}{S_i}\Leftrightarrow\exists i\in I:x\in S_i$$
Is this statement:

1. a definition?
2. a theorem/corollary?
3. (related to) an axiom?

If case 2. is true, could you provide an outline of the proof? Else, if case 3. is true, could you inform be about this axiom and its relation to the statement?

Answer (score 3):

$$\huge ~~~~~~~~~~1~~~~~~~~~~$$

Comment: (Pardon the brevity of this answer!)

Comment: No problem, I appreciate brevity anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is usually the definition I see for $\bigcup S_i$. A set is defined by its membership predicate, which is what this definition is doing: an element $x$ is a member of $\bigcup S_i$ if, and only if, it is in one of the $S_i$s.